# What is wrong with inheritance of generic

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a question about generics.

I defined base classes `ServiceObject` and `ServiceObjectsList`

```
class ServiceObject {};
class ServiceObjectsList<T extends ServiceObject> extends ArrayList<T> {};
```

Then I defined some descendant classes:

```
class UserServiceObject extends ServiceObject {};
class UserServiceObjectsList extends ServiceObjectsList<UserServiceObject> {};

class ItemServiceObject extends ServiceObject {};
class ItemServiceObjectsList extends ServiceObjectsList<ItemServiceObject> {};

// etc...
```

Now I need to treat `UserServiceObjectsList` as `ServiceObjectsList<ServiceObject>`:

If I write:

```
ServiceObjectsList displayableServiceObjects;
```

then I can't iterate over them:

```
for (ServiceObject serviceObject : displayableServiceObjects)
```

throw error "Incompatible types".

If I write `ServiceObjectsList<ServiceObject> displayableServiceObjects`
then I can't assign `UserServiceObjects`:

```
displayableServiceObjects = new UserServiceObjects();
```

It throws the very same "Incompatible types" error;

What I do wrong?

All `ServiceObject`s, `ServiceObjectsList`s and they descendants realy needed. Then encapsulate some functional.

Comment: How does `ServiceObjects displayableServiceObjects;` even compile? You haven't shown a declaration for a `ServiceObjects` type.

Comment: Ok. I decleared <T extends ServiceObject> in ServiceObjectsList class declaration. Does not it plays sence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the generic type in the declaration:

```
ServiceObjectsList<? extends ServiceObject> displayableServiceObjects;
```

and the "Incompatible types" error will be gone...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat your list as `ServiceObjectsList<ServiceObject>`, because that is not what it is. Casting is not allowed.

You CAN however cast you list as `ServiceObjectsList<? extends ServiceObject>` - a list of something that extends `ServiceObject`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is what I *think* you're trying to achieve  do can't be done, because ArrayList and ArrayList aren't really separate classes like they are in C++, where templates are more like clever macros than Java generics.

When you define `class ServiceObjectsList<T extends ServiceObject> extends ArrayList<T> {}` you have created a proper subclass of ArrayList, but ServiceObjectsList is still generic. Then when you declare a variable `ServiceObjectsList displayableServiceObjects;` without adding a type parameter, it's the same as `ServiceObjectsList<Object>`. The qualifier `<T extends ServiceObject>` will be checked at compile-time, but only if you declare a type-parameter on your variable.